# Playing two files in a row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, playlist, event-listener

I can't get this right. So, I'm making a simple script that tells the current time.
*audiocontainer* is an audio element, and the *mp3play()* function has been defned earlier.
The idea is to do that:

[play hourXX.mp3] -> when it ends -> [play minutesXX.mp3] -> delete listener, therefore stop.

- The problem is:

**Without** the removeEventListener() function, the minuteXX.mp3 loops indefinitely ("It's 12 and 54 minutes... 54 minutes... 54 minutes...) because it keeps triggering the listener at the end.

**With** the removeEventListener() function the audio doesn't start at all. Do you have any idea why?

Or maybe is there any simpler way to play 2 mp3 in a row?

```
function telltime() {
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();

audiocontainer.addEventListener('ended', function () {
mp3play('./time/minutes/minute'+m.toString()+'.mp3');

audiocontainer.removeEventListener('ended', function(), false); // stop!

}, true);

mp3play('./time/hours/hour'+h.toString()+'.mp3');

}
```

Comment: there is a syntax error on that line. That's why. `function()` without anything else isn't valid (and actually doesn't make any sense)

Comment: Just for the record, here's my logic (maybe someone else will learn from the mistake): From what I knew, if you wanted to destroy the EventListener, you needed to refer to it the same way it was created. So I needed to place the name of the function inside removeEventListener as well. Since I created the Listener with a nested nameless function (which worked without problems), I figured I'd refer to it just by the same "name" - function().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your problem is a bit "localized" (it doesn't work because of syntax errors), I've abstracted your question to allow me to provide an answer that is useful for others too.

## How to play multiple mp3 files in a row

include this into your context:

```
var Mp3Queue = function(container, files) {
    var index = 1;
    if(!container || !container.tagName || container.tagName !== 'AUDIO')throw 'Invalid container';
    if(!files || !files.length)throw 'Invalid files array';        

    var playNext = function() {
        if(index < files.length) {
            container.src = files[index];
            index += 1;
        } else {
            container.removeEventListener('ended', playNext, false);
        }
    };

    container.addEventListener('ended', playNext);

    container.src = files[0];
};
```

use it like this:

```
//whatever is your audio element
var container = document.getElementById('container'); 

//play files in a row
new Mp3Queue(container, [
    'http://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Sweeter%20Vermouth.mp3',
    'http://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Happy%20Boy%20Theme.mp3'
]);
```

here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fYjLx/

In your specific case that would be:

```
function telltime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();

    new Mp3Queue(container, [
        './time/hours/hour'+h.toString()+'.mp3',
        './time/minutes/minute'+m.toString()+'.mp3'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Talk about a useful answer! I'll analyze every bit of that to understand how it works.