# Play audio files in sequence but with delays between each song

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have three audio files which last for 3 seconds each. I am able to detect when the first song finishes by using the callback function as shown below. I want the second song to start 5 seconds later and the third 10 seconds later. How can i achieve this?

```
 var song = $('#player1');
    var song2 = $('#player2');
    var song3 = $('#player3');

    song.get(0).play();
    song.bind("ended", function(){
        song2.get(0).play();
        song2.bind("ended", function(){
            //song3 code goes here
        });

    });
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916896/playing-two-files-in-a-row-in-javascript

Comment: song2.get(0).play(); should be  setTimeout(function(){song2.get(0).play();}, 5000)